# Printing out the contents of /dev/nvme devices : what does it represent?

Tags: devices

Out of curiosity I've decided to call cat on one of my nvme devices with the following command :
`sudo cat /dev/nvme0n1p1`
It started printing out gibberish but now I wonder : what data does this actually represent ? Is it data from somewhere on the disk ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is the data from all of the partition. You could even use this for e.g. creating an image of the partition. You may test this if you have a smaller partition available, e.g. a `EFI`-boot partition that often is no more than half a gigabyte.

```
lsblk
#nvme0n1     259:0    0 476.9G  0 disk 
#├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   276M  0 part /boot/efi
#├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0    70G  0 part /
#├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0     1G  0 part 
#├─nvme0n1p6 259:4    0 353.9G  0 part /data
#└─nvme0n1p7 259:5    0  11.2G  0 part [SWAP]

cat /dev/nvme0n1p1 > /data/boot.iso
mount /data/boot.iso /mnt
ls /mnt
#EFI   loader  'System Volume Information'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats the data that is stored on the device, in this case partition 1.

You can actually clone the device or partitions on the device using the `cat` command:

```
 cat /dev/nvme0n1p1 > /dev/sdd1
```

That command would clone the partition `/dev/nvme0n1p1` to partition `/dev/sdd1`.